# How do I respond with a message to a user when they trigger an error on my Discord bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make my Discord bot reply to a user letting them know that there was an error if one occurred when they ran a command. I'm unsure of how I'm supposed to get my message variable from the command message in my index file from the command.

I've already tried using the message variable in a function that is running in my index.js file from the command file, but when it runs it says that 'message' is not defined. I suspect that it may be where I've put my `.catch()`. Here is the code that I am using.

```
//This is the area in my index that handles errors
bot.on('error', (err, message) => {
  console.error();
  message.reply("error here, possibly a rich presence");
});

//Heres the function with the .catch()
http.request(options, function(res) {
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body+= chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
       var jsondata = JSON.parse(body);
       var converteddate = new Date(jsondata.toTimestamp*1000)
       console.log(converteddate)
       var hours = converteddate.getHours();
       var minutes = "0" + converteddate.getMinutes();
       var finishedtime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2);
        message.reply(finishedtime + " EST.")
})
}).end()
.catch(err => bot.emit('error', err, message));
}
```

The expected output of this is to run the command and if there are any errors, notify the user of them. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the form of the input (the 'command' he's running)? 
If you just want to print the error, just do a `message.channel.send(err)` in the `bot.on` part.
But if you need something else, please add detail to your question. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It listens for a message, then it makes an HTTP request then replies to the message with the output of it.

Comment: in your catch you can simply do: `message.author.send("There was an error: "+err);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so first you have a problem with your '}' (there's one that shouldn't be here at the end)

Then, a simple example how to catch:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function error() {
  await sleep(3000); // wait 5 sec for the sake of the example
  throw 'I have a problem';
}
console.log('starting')
error().catch((err) => console.log('The error:',err))
```

I'm not sure what is the `.end()`, but I think you don't need it

So here, you want to do :

```
http.request(options, function(){
    // do something
    return 'text message'; // what you want to reply
}).catch((err) => err).then((msg) => message.reply(msg))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the message because in the `http.request` isn't close properly. Make sure you run a linter and bveautify your code to easily spot extra or unclosed sections in your code.

as for replying to the user you could simply do:

```
message.author.send("There was an error: "+err);
```

I would try something like this:

```
http.request(options, (res) => {
    let body = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body+= chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
       const jsondata = JSON.parse(body);
       const converteddate = new Date(jsondata.toTimestamp*1000)
       console.log(converteddate)
       const hours = converteddate.getHours();
       const minutes = "0" + converteddate.getMinutes();
       const finishedtime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2);
        message.reply(finishedtime + " EST.")
    })
}).catch(err => message.author.send("There was an error: "+err.toString()));
```

If you want to do a more global approach I would create a errorHandler and import it. However I do not see any particular reason to have a generic one since you do not do any specific actions with it.